# CountVectorizer but for group of text

Tags: python, scikit-learn, vectorization

Using the following code, CountVectorizer break "Air-dried meat" into 3 different vector. But What I want is to keep "Air-dried meat" as 1 vector. how do I do it?

The code I run:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
food_names = ['Air-dried meat', 'Almonds', 'Amaranth']
count_vect = CountVectorizer(binary=True)
bow_rep = count_vect.fit(food_names)
#Look at the vocabulary mapping
print("Our vocabulary: ", count_vect.vocabulary_)
```

Current output:

```
Our vocabulary:  {'air': 0, 'dried': 3, 'meat': 4, 'almonds': 1, 'amaranth': 2}
```

Desired outpput:

```
Our vocabulary:  {'air-dried meat': 3, 'almonds': 1, 'amaranth': 2}
```

Comment: if you use `'Air_dried_meat'` then it will treat it as single word. But it may not be useful for other code.

Comment: see options in [CountVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) - ie. `token_pattern`. If you use `CountVectorizer(binary=True, token_pattern='.+')` then it will treat every element on list as single word.

Comment: @furas I have a follow up question if you don't mind:  after fitting the data like you showed, I try to fit a sentence 
`temp = count_vect.transform(["Almonds of Germany"])
print("Almonds of Germany", temp.toarray())`
the outcome for this is [[0, 0, 0]] Expected outcome is [0, 1, 0] as the world "Almonds" is included. How can I do that?

Comment: if you use `token_pattern='.+'` then it seems it use it also to split `"Almonds of Germany"` and it treats `Almonds of Germany` as one word. You could split manually text into list `["Almonds", "of", "Germany"])` but it gives for every word separated results - `[0 1 0]  [0 0 0]  [0 0 0]`. You may have to use `tokenizer=shlex.split` and `" "` in `'"Air-dried meat"'`

Comment: understood. thanks!

Comment: I found other method - you can convert `food_names` to `lower()` and use directly as vocabulary - `CountVectorizer(binary=True, vocabulary=food_names)` - but later it will not add new elements when you use `fit()`. But it will split `Almonds of Germany` into words in `transform()`. But `transform()` will treat `Air-dried meat` as three words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use options in [CountVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) to change behaviour - ie. `token_pattern` or `tokenizer`.

---

If you use `token_pattern='.+'`

```
CountVectorizer(binary=True, token_pattern='.+')
```

then it will treat every element on list as single word.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

food_names = ['Air-dried meat', 'Almonds', 'Amaranth']

count_vect = CountVectorizer(binary=True, token_pattern='.+')
bow_rep = count_vect.fit(food_names)

print("Our vocabulary:", count_vect.vocabulary_)
```

Result:

```
Our vocabulary: {'air-dried meat': 0, 'almonds': 1, 'amaranth': 2}
```

---

If you use `tokenizer=shlex.split`

```
CountVectorizer(binary=True, tokenizer=shlex.split)
```

then you can use `" "` to group words in string

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import shlex

food_names = ['"Air-dried meat" other words', 'Almonds', 'Amaranth']

count_vect = CountVectorizer(binary=True, tokenizer=shlex.split)
bow_rep = count_vect.fit(food_names)

print("Our vocabulary:", count_vect.vocabulary_)
```

Result:

```
Our vocabulary: {'air-dried meat': 0, 'other': 3, 'words': 4, 'almonds': 1, 'amaranth': 2}
```

---

BTW: similar question on portal for [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

[how to avoid tokenizing w/ sklearn feature extraction](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/54904/how-to-avoid-tokenizing-w-sklearn-feature-extraction)

---

**EDIT:**

You can also convert `food_names` to `lower()` and use as `vocabulary`

```
vocabulary = [x.lower() for x in food_names]

count_vect = CountVectorizer(binary=True, vocabulary=vocabulary)
```

and it also will treat it as single elemement in vocabulary

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

food_names = ["Air-dried meat", "Almonds", "Amaranth"]
vocabulary = [x.lower() for x in food_names]

count_vect = CountVectorizer(binary=True, vocabulary=vocabulary)

bow_rep = count_vect.fit(food_names)
print("Our vocabulary:", count_vect.vocabulary_)
```

---

Problem is when you want to use these methods with `transform()` because only `tokenizer=shlex.split` splits text in transformed text. But it also need `" "` in text to catch `Air-dried meat`

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import shlex

food_names = ['"Air-dried meat" Almonds Amaranth']

count_vect = CountVectorizer(binary=True, tokenizer=shlex.split)
bow_rep = count_vect.fit(food_names)
print("Our vocabulary:", count_vect.vocabulary_)

text = 'Almonds of Germany'
temp = count_vect.transform([text])
print(text, temp.toarray())

text = '"Air-dried meat"'
temp = count_vect.transform([text])
print(text, temp.toarray())

text = 'Air-dried meat'
temp = count_vect.transform([text])
print(text, temp.toarray())
```